# Output parameter gives different result in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have stored proc in which I am calling another stored proc.

```
 Declare @itemNumber varchar(20),@productID int
 EXEC usp_find_productID
    @itemNumber = '35677',
    @productID = @productID OUTPUT
```

This sp returns productID in variable @productID but also as resultset table.
Can somebody tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will bet you a donut that inside the stored procedure you will find something like:

```
SELECT @ProductID
```

And that the stored procedure is actually different on the two servers.

Of course we can't tell, because you didn't post the important part (the actual stored procedure code).